# specify colorRamp endpoints

Tags: r, colors, gradient, plotly, r-corrplot

Can I specify endpoints to `colorRamp` so that a value maps consistently to a single color, regardless of the range of other data?

I'm trying to create an interactive correlation plot in `plotly`.  Here's some sample data.

```
set.seed(1)
m <- 4
cm <- matrix(runif(m**2,-1,1),
             nrow=m, ncol=m,
             dimnames=list(letters[1:m],letters[1:m]))
diag(cm) <- 1

cm
#            a          b          c          d
# a  1.0000000 -0.5966361  0.2582281  0.3740457
# b -0.2557522  1.0000000 -0.8764275 -0.2317926
# c  0.1457067  0.8893505  1.0000000  0.5396828
# d  0.8164156  0.3215956 -0.6468865  1.0000000
```

I'm basically trying to create an interactive version of this:

```
library(corrplot)
corrplot(cm,method='shade')
```

[image: Non-interactive version of desired output]

Here's the (kind of hacky) interactive correlation plot I created.

```
div_colors <- c('dark red','white','navy blue')
grid_labels <- matrix(paste0('Cor(',
                               do.call(paste,c(expand.grid(rownames(cm),colnames(cm)), sep=', ') ),
                               '): ', 
                               t(round(cm,2))
                             ),
                             ncol=m,byrow=TRUE)
library(plotly)
plot_ly(x = colnames(cm),
        y = rownames(cm),
        z = cm,
        colors = colorRamp(div_colors),
        type='heatmap',
        hoverinfo='text',
        text = grid_labels
        ) %>% layout(yaxis=list(autorange='reversed'))
```

[image]

My problem is that without forcing the `colorRamp` endpoints to `c(-1,1)`, the white color doesn't match correlation of 0, and the dark red maps to the minimum observed, rather than -1.

Comment: set [zmin and zmax](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#heatmap-zmin)?

Comment: @rawr that works.  I'll accept it as an answer if you want to write it up.  Kind of trivial, but it wasn't in any of the examples (e.g. [here](https://plot.ly/r/heatmaps/#custom-colorscales) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @rawr mentioned in a comment, the solution is to [set `zmin` and `zmax`](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#heatmap-zmin), as in:

```
plot_ly(x = colnames(cm),
        y = rownames(cm),
        z = cm,
        zmin=-1,                         #   <============
        zmax=1,                          #   <============
        colors = colorRamp(div_colors),
        type='heatmap',
        hoverinfo='text',
        text = grid_labels
) %>% layout(yaxis=list(autorange='reversed'))
```

Which produces the desired result.  (The legend bar is shorter, presumably due to a change in default sizes in a newer version of plotly.)
[image]